# Unable to renew or create Group Event Subscriptions due to x-anchor mailbox

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have a web application that creates Group Event Subscriptions.  It has been working fine for over a year.  This week, I started noticing that subscriptions aren't being renewed or created.

In troubleshooting, I see this error:

```
Code: ExtensionError
Message: Operation: Delete; 
Exception: [Status Code: BadRequest
Reason: The x-anchor mailbox 'OID:[User Object ID]@[Tenant Id]' does not match the target of the request.]
```

My payload is consistent with the Graph Documentation with the resource being `Groups/[GroupId]/Events`

Now, if I do nothing more than remove `Events` from this subscription request, a subscription to the group is created just fine. This means that the problem is isolated to the Group Event resource.  I also have the same error for Group Conversations.

I am creating the subscription within the client's context.

I notice that [something has changed on the backend](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/error-improvement-for-invalid-x-anchormailbox-in-rest-api-calls/). So, it appears that at the moment, no event or conversation subscriptions for groups can be created and subscriptions that I previously created/renewed that go out of date tonight will all fail.

I think that the error is really just a generic error and that this actually doesn't have anything to do with the `X-AnchorMailbox` header; however, I cannot be sure.  I think this really is just an error that meant that the request is properly formatted, but that the subscription cannot be created.

Can someone confirm whether or not this is a new bug.  If not, I am curious what has changed that I need to address in code.

I have tried different groups, tenants, and to reduce the requested `changetype` to `updated` only.  I have attempted to add the `X-AnchorMailbox` header.

None work.

Here is my post from Graph Explorer

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
Content-type: application/json

{
   "changeType": "created,deleted,updated",
   "notificationUrl": "https://[...]/Webhook-Calendar-Receiver?code=[code omitted]",
   "resource": "Groups/[group id omitted]/Events",
   "expirationDateTime":"2019-04-15T03:14:45.9356913Z",
   "clientState": "[client state omitted]"
}
```

I expect a response with the subscription details in the body.

Comment: I can confirm that group events no longer work as triggers for Microsoft Flows either.   While it appears that you can use the OOB flow trigger for group events, it will never actually trigger and you cannot test the flow either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem three days ago. This morning, I executed the call to create a subscription to threads in a group and it works great. (unable to comment [no reputation])

UPDATE:
This morning no patch or create works... It's a little weird, does Microsoft Graph still have problems?

UPDATE #2: 
I contacted Microsoft support and they didn't solve the problem. It seems to work most of the time, but when it doesn't work, it's for a few days.